# Why angular momentum keeps the giroscope standing in "impossible" orientations?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, angular-velocity

I am trying to understand how gyroscopes can maintain rotation in different "impossible" orientations when spinning.

I saw that the behaviour in zero-g is slightly different. On Earth, the gyroscope rotates but with the same rotation axis, however, in space, the gyro seems to maintain fixed to a direction. Can someone explain the physics behind it with equations?